# grails callback when controller recompiled in runtime

Tags: grails, grails-orm, jit

I am overwriting the redirect method of every controller I wrote. I did that because

a) I need to set some variables before the redirect is actually executed

b) I want to do that globally because it is the same code for every controller and I want to be DRY

I did this in the bootstrap because it is executed when the server starts.

Code:

```
grailsApplication.controllerClasses.each() { controllerClass ->
    if (controllerClass.fullName.startsWith("my.package")){
        def oldRedirect = controllerClass.metaClass.pickMethod("redirect", [Map] as Class[])
        controllerClass.metaClass.redirect = { Map args ->
            // pre-redirect logic
            args.put("some", "property")                
            oldRedirect.invoke delegate, args
            // post-redirect logic
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the problem:

When I am developing, I use the reloading feature / just in time compiler which recompiles the file without the need to restart the server. In this case the controller is rebuilt and as a result the overwritten redirect method is lost.

Here is the question:

Is there a callback / another way to find out when a class is recompiled in runtime? I would love to check if a controller was rebuild and then overwrite the redirect method again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, break this functionality out into a plugin and you can then observe reloading of classes and re-apply your changes. The [documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/plugins.html#participatingInAutoReloadEvents) goes into great detail on participating in auto reload events.

This would be the cleanest, and most proper way to accomplish what you are looking to do.

Comment: sounds great and thanks for your solution. But it seems like a lot of overhead to create a plugin for this tiny feature. Do you have an idea to do this without a plugin?

Comment: No idea on how to do it without a plugin. In fact, that's a good indication that the right way is to use a plugin. It's not as much overhead as you think to create a plugin. It's very easy once you get the hang of it and it's a good tool to have in your toolbox. Plugins are very powerful for many reasons.

Comment: Thanks. A plugin it will be. Can you give me a hint on how I can include the plugin locally?

Comment: Yep, inline plugins (as they are called) are added to your `BuildConfig.groovy` like this: `grails.plugin.location."my-plugin" = "../my-plugin"` ... the value is the path, it can be relative to your project or absolute. Prior to the section that says `grails.project.fork = [`

Comment: Cool. thanks. One last question: When I put the plugin in that folder - does it need to be in source code or in zip or another format?

Comment: In the case of inline plugins, that's a directory which contains the plugin project in source format as you would keep it for working on it.

Comment: thanks. You are the best! To help others: This git repo does nearly the same https://github.com/Netflix-Skunkworks/grails-context-param/blob/master/ContextParamGrailsPlugin.groovy